# Linq Join in c#

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-entities

friend i'm working in Linq. I use join in linq query with Entity Model as below.

```
var Records = from Cats in Context.Categories
join prod in Context.Products on Cats.Id equals prod.Category_Id
select new { CatName = Cats.Name, ProdName = prod.Name };
```

i want to convert the Record var in List of object, so i create a intermediate object which hold both entites values(product,category). Now when i cast this var to list like

```
List<test> testList = (List<test>)Records;
```

as Record.ToList(); is compiler error. how i cast the var object to list in order to bind it with listview in frontend. Is there any alternative in lambda which will be also appreciated. Is my approach is right?

my test class is as:

```
class test{
string catname;
string productname;
}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with the join itself, but rather with the casting, right? Btw, if you get an error, it's a good practice to actually TELL US the error, so we don't have to guess...

Comment: What is your `test` type definition?

Comment: test is my class which hold category and product fields in order to get record from more then one column.

Comment: @NomiAli please add the details of your `test` class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create `new Test` and set the properties accordingly and finally  call `ToList`

```
List<test> testList = (from c in Context.Categories
join p in Context.Products on c.Id equals p.Category_Id
select new Test{ Category= c, Product= p}).ToList();
```

If have class like below

```
public class Test{

    public string CatName{ get; set; }
    public string ProductnName{ get; set; }

}

List<test> testList = (from c in Context.Categories
join p in Context.Products on c.Id equals p.Category_Id
select new Test{ CatName= c.Name, ProductnName= p.Name}).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

use `ToList()` on your query.

```
var Records = (from Cats in Context.Categories
               join prod in Context.Products on Cats.Id equals prod.Category_Id
               select new test { CatName = Cats.Name, ProdName = prod.Name }).ToList();
```

In order to make it work you need to define your test class as follows (you need to define properties)

```
public class test {
   public string catname {get;set;}
   public string productname {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Anonymous object still will not be casted to `test` type

Comment: how to cast that object? @lazyberezovsky

Comment: @lazyberezovsky ok you are correct. Missed that. the problem is only what is `Test`